# Network interface binding only working for root user

Tags: networking, server, permissions, lts, netplan

I have a computer running Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 (using netplan for networking), and I am running into an issue where programs that support binding to a network interface continue to use the default route unless I run them as root. For example, when I run a command such `curl --interface myinterface ipchecker.example.com` rather than binding to myinterface, curl still sends the traffic through the default route (unless I run it as root).

On my other computer running Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 (using NetworkManager for networking), this problem doesn't exist, and I can freely bind to interfaces without root privileges. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu Server and netplan?

Comment: Look at `ip route show`, or `ip r`, read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: @waltinator I'm not adding the second interface's routes to the routing table, because I want all programs to go through the default route, except for the programs which I have specifically told to bind to the other interface. I don't want to touch the routing table. This works fine when using NetworkManager, but there's something about systemd-networkd and netplan that's causing issues with this approach.